# Can we say "watering vegetables"?

Tags: word-usage

Do you say in English *watering vegetables*? For example in a garden?
Or do you say only *watering the flowers*?

Does the following sentence make sense in English?

> They’ll be doing exercises outside when Rebecca starts watering vegetables.

Comment: In my mind "watering" as used here envisions watering such plants from above the ground (say from a watering pot), which is OK for flowers but usually not done with vegetables. For vegetables I would use "irrigate" or "put the water on" which mean adding water at ground level.

Comment: @user3169 -- In California, the ditchtenders who distribute irrigation water use phrases like "water the grapes" synonymously with "irrigate the grapes", regardless of whether the farmer has a drip system, a sprinkler system, or just uses "flood irrigation".

Answer (score 1):

The sentence that makes most sense is

> They’ll be doing exercises outside when Rebecca starts watering **the** vegetables.

Unless *watering vegetables* is some specific activity, which I've never heard of but may exist or is some personal activity that Rebecca enjoys.

For example

> They’ll be doing exercises outside when Rebecca starts watering vegetables.  It helps her relax.

There is a very subtle distinction here.  It's not any specific vegetables, even those in the garden.  It's just that Rebecca likes to water vegetables, whatever vegetables are available.

A similar construct would be

> Rebecca likes to water vegetables in the afternoon to help her relax.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with your own example, from a purely grammatical point of view it should be:

> ... when Rebecca starts watering **the** vegetables.

Now, as for usage, this specific phrase does seem to be a bit unusual, I believe mostly because the word **vegetables** by itself is more commonly used to refer to the harvested produce, ie. when they no longer need watering. People will understand what you mean but might need a double take.

Common alternatives from around the web:

> ... when Rebecca starts watering the vegetable garden.
>
> ... when Rebecca starts watering the vegetable plants.

Both of these specify that you are not talking about the harvested produce.

Comment: I disagree that the use of "watering the vegetables" would prompt a double-take, and see no need to append a word like _plants_ or _garden_ for clarification. This usage is far from "unusual," and fits well within standard [dictionary definitions of the word](https://www.wordnik.com/words/vegetable).

Comment: I have heard 'watering the vegetables' used in Britain as a jocular euphemism for urination.

Comment: Many (UK and former colony) speakers are likely to use **watering the veges** as the popular shorthand for vegetables. You are also likely to come across the phrase: **meat and three veg** referring to a meal in which three varieties of vegetable are served with meat.  http://thekitchencoach.com.au/blogmain/meat-three-veg-is-bad-for-you      http://www.bite.co.nz/hot-topics/in-season/2264/Modern-meat-and-three-veg-combinations/

Comment: I was going to upvote this until I read the longer comments around how *watering the vegetables* sounds odd (it doesn't) and how *watering the vegetable plants* would be a more common alternative (in no way at all). See [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=watering+the+vegetables%2Cwatering+the+vegetable+garden%2Cwatering+the+vegetable+plants&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwatering%20the%20vegetables%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwatering%20the%20vegetable%20garden%3B%2Cc0). The statements are wrong even for the US specifically.